# Can we share video from external camera to iOS device

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I have a requirement like i have Camera which has blutooth and i can connect the camera to iOS device thru bluetooth, and capture the video some thing similar to the below link concept, Which frameworks we can use?

http://www.looxcie.com/

Comment: Be careful. If it's with Bluetooth, you'll have to deal with MFI (ExternalAccessory.framework). Bluetooth Low-Energy (you tagged with Core-Bluetooth) is not done for images/videos. And Bluetooth shouldn't be enough for video (their products with Bluetooth I saw are very low quality of video images). Wi-Fi is the best solution for video streaming.

Comment: to Use Wifi - we don't need MFI License right ?

Answer (score 0):

Before doing anything, be sure that your camera is MFI.

See the link below to learn more about the MFI program

https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/